# StoryBoardを使って端末(4s,5s,6sなど)ごとにImageViewやButtonのサイズを変更したい

Tags: swift, ios, storyboard

最近StoryBoardを使い始めたのですが、端末ごとにうまく画像やButtonの配置ができません。
例えば画像のようにたくさんのButtonを均等に配置する場合、Buttonのwidthとheightを先に指定してしまうため、6sや5sではうまく画面に収まった場合でも、4sでは画面からButtonがはみ出してしまいます。
今回は出来るだけコードを書かずにStoryBoardを使って実装したいと考えています。
先にwidthとheightを指定せずに画面の比率からうまくサイズを調整したいのですが、コードを書かずにAutoLayoutだけで実装することは可能でしょうか？現在Buttonのwidthとheightをviewのwidthの1/5のサイズにできないかと考えています。
もし可能な場合は、そのやり方を教えていただけないでしょうか？宜しくお願いいたします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Buttonのwidthとheightをviewのwidthの1/5のサイズにできないか

はい、できます。

まず、View Controller上に、ビュー（ボタン、Image Viewなど）を配置し、横幅を、正確にベースViewの横幅の1/5にします。
そして、Document Outline上で、ベースViewと、配置したViewを、Commandキーを押しながら両選択します（下図）。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**Pin**をクリックして、ポップオーバーを表示し、**Equal Widths**にチェックを入れ、Add Constraintします（下図）。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

つぎに、Constraintを選択して、そのSize Inspectorを表示します。**Multiplier**を0.2（5分の1）に設定します（下図）。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

これで、ベースViewの横幅5分の1の、ビューの横幅を設定できます。ほかの必要なConstraintsを設定してください。
iOSシミュレータで、iPhone 4s、iPhone 6s Plusで実行したスクリーンショットです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力][image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

スクリーンサイズにより、ビューのサイズが可変になっているのがわかります。

Comment: この方法でうまくサイズを調整することができました。
ベースViewと、配置したViewをまとめて制約をつける方法は思いつきませんでした。本当に有難うございます！